# How to save the instance of mediaPlayer in an activity before calling finish()?

Tags: android, android-activity, instance, android-mediaplayer

Am calling activity B from activity A. In activity B am creating a mediaPlayer instance and calling finish(), after when i return again to activity B from activity A new mediaPlayer instance is created. how to save the instance before calling the finish() and restore everytime i call activity B.